# 3 congruent to certain quadratic form mod p, does it imply that p is congruent to 1 or 11 mod 12

Tags: number-theory

I'm working on something and came across the following number theory problem:

Let $p$  be a prime at least $5$ and $\ell^{2}+\ell k+k^{2}\equiv3$ (mod $p$). Where $\ell$, $k$ are solutions of the linear diophantine equation

$-3\ell+4k=12$

Is it true that $p\equiv\pm1$ (mod$12$)?

It is always true if $\ell$ or $k$ is $0$, which is just quadratic reciprocity. I did some numerical testing and find it true in a lot of cases.

More generally I'm interested in the case when $\ell$, $k$ are solutions of

$a\ell+bk=2c$

Where $a,b,c$ are integers satisfying the equation

$a^{2}+b^{2}-ab=1+c^{2}$   (for example $(a,b,c)=(-3,4,6)$ is a solution)

I did some numerical testing for solutions other than $(-3,4,6)$ and find the assertion true in those cases as well. I couldn't really find in the literature where this type of problem is studied, nor am I solid enough in number theory to attempt this myself. So if any expert can offer some help, I will be really appreciated.

Comment: The general case should be amenable to the same method as that shown below. I'll have a look in the morning if you haven't solved it already by then.

Answer (score 2):

Your first result is indeed correct.

You can eliminate $l$ and obtain $(37k-66)^2\equiv{27}$ (mod $p$).

Then $(\frac {3}{p})=+1$ and quadratic reciprocity gives $p\equiv\pm1$ (mod $12$).

Answer (score 1):

**The general case** (All congruences are modulo $p$)

$$a^2l^2+a^2lk+a^2k^2\equiv 3a^2$$ Replace $al+bk$ by $2c$, expand and simplify:
$$(1+c^2)k^2+2c(a-2b)k+4c^2\equiv 3a^2$$
Multiply by $1+c^2$ and replace $(1+c^2)k$ by $K$:
$$K^2+2c(a-2b)K+(4c^2-3a^2)(1+c^2)\equiv 0$$ Complete the square:
$$(K+c(a-2b))^2\equiv (3a^2-4c^2)(1+c^2)+c^2(a-2b)^2 \equiv 3a^2-4c^2-4c^4+4c^2(a^2+b^2-ab)\equiv3a^2$$
So, providing $p$ is an odd prime which is not a factor of $a$, $(\frac{3}{p})=+1$ and quadratic reciprocity gives

$p\equiv\pm1$ (mod $12$).

Comment: Thanks very much, it helps a lot! And guess we can always assume p is not a factor of a, since p cannot be factor of both a and b.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Of course. $p$ ca be a factor of $a$ which is why $p=3$ had to be excluded in your first result.